# Automating password reset in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I want to automate the password reset in salesforce for 10 specific users everytime. For doing this I have written a Apex class in salesforce. And I  want to schedule this class also.But I am new in Apex coding.

Here is the class that I have written:

```
public class DataTeam_ResetPassword
{

public DataTeam_ResetPassword()
{

    List<id> DteamIDs = new List<id>{'005A0000003ja3x'};


    for(Id u : DteamIDs)
    {
        system.setPassword(u,'qweEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'werwEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'wetEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'dsfEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'bhcvEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'dhEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'fjfjEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'tyEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'tweEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'mmEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'rwrEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'jkgkEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'5y4yEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'kjEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'asgaghEfetividade_1');
        system.setPassword(u,'Efafwrwrw_1');
      }
  }           
}
```

can any one help me what next should I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You may be better server by having a common profile for all the required users and then having a specific password policy for that profile. See [Set Session Timeout and Password Policies for Individual Profiles](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_profile_additions.htm)

---

Create an [Apex Scheduler](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) and use [System.resetPassword(ID userID, Boolean send_user_email)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_resetPassword).

```
global class scheduledPasswordReset implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        Boolean sendUserEmail = true;
        System.resetPassword('005A0000003ja3x', sendUserEmail);
        // Repeat for other User Ids to reset.
    }
}
```

Start with something like:

```
scheduledPasswordReset m = new scheduledPasswordReset();
String sch = '20 30 8 10 2 ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('Reset Password Job', sch, m);
```

Alter the [expression](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm#d36429e366-d36837e111) above to run as required.

Comment: I want to schedule it to run once after every 60 days from now. what should be the CronExpression?

Comment: I don't think you can use a cron expression for an interval longer than once a month. Maybe run once a day and check when it was last run? Or calculate the date 60 days from now and schedule it for that explicit date.